# SQL: Is it bad to use create on database and tables that already exist?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

I want to have a script on my Nodejs Server of database initialization that will run everytime the server is initialized, that is, that all the required databases and tables will be created if they are not already.
so if I'm just doing something like:

```
CREATE DATABASE newtest;
USE newtest;
CREATE TABLE people(id INT(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL);
```

could it be bad, in opposition to checking every time if a database or table exists, and only if not then create it. I mean, as long as it doesn't kill my script and only returns an error as parameter and continues it's fine, isn't it? Want to make sure.

Thanks

Comment: There are options on most things which is `IF NOT EXISTS`, so `create database if not exists newtest;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is fine, in fact, most of the db frameworks (like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/)) use this approach during db initialisation/application startup.

If you want to do it manually, using your own custom script then you can use `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schema`.`Employee` (
id int
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually found a problem with multiple statements and that's solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I consider creating a database in this way to be a bad practice, in general.

Creating a database is not (necessarily) a trivial operation.  Space needs to be allocated for the tables, system tables need to be generated and updated.  In addition, there are optimizations that might be made at the database level.  It should not be though of as an atomic operation.

In general, an application would be accessing one or a handful of databases.  These databases should be set up and defined before the application starts running.  In other words, the environment should be ready for the application.

Does that mean it is *always* wrong to be creating databases in application code?  No.  But doing so should be extremely rare and done only with a lot of caution.